# Re-using a stringstream after iteration with istreambuf_iterator

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stringstream, streambuf

If I pass an `istreambuf_iterator` wrapper around a `stringstream` to a function which requires such an iterator, how can I re-use (overwrite) the stream's existing buffer after the function has returned, without triggering a heap allocation?
(`clear` seems to cause re-allocation when a new character is inserted.)

Comment: Unfortunately, I doubt there's much you can do. At least to my recollection, the standard doesn't specify much (anything?) in the way of requirements about when a streambuf can/can't reallocate.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: I'm dealing with Visual C++ though, that's a lot more specific than generic C++.

Comment: Thinking a bit more, have you tried just a `seekp(0)` to start writing from the beginning again?

Comment: Have you tried managing the buffer explicitly with `rdbuf`?

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Huh... that seems to be doing the trick (I combined it with `seekg`). Although I'm still not sure since the CRT code is really hard to read and I haven't tested it a lot yet... but I'm not noticing any heap allocations at the moment. Thanks for the pointer (no pun intended).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: I had, but I wasn't sure what to do with it exactly.